# How to display terminal output in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, terminal

How to display terminal output live in a window using tkinter?
I used subprocess method but I didn't get what I wanted. Do you know another way?

I want to show terminal output live in tkinter

subprocess.Popen(
command,
shell=True,
stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
text=True,
bufsize=1,
)